# The sendmessage function send the message repeatly

Tags: c#, sendmessage

**Code**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

public Window SendKey(int key)
{
    SendKey(Message.WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr((Int32)key), new IntPtr(0))
    .SendKey(Message.WM_KEYUP, new IntPtr((Int32)key), new IntPtr(0));
    return this;
}

private Window SendKey(uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    SendMessage(_windowHandler, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    return this;
}
var wind = new Window(new IntPtr(0x000601f2));
wind.SendKey(Keys.VK_F5);
```

**Result**

The `F5` key doesn't refresh the web browser and it send the messages like figure below:
[image]

Anyone have any ideas about this issue?

Comment: It is not sent twice.  This is just an artifact of Spy++, it shows a notification both when the window begins processing the message (S = sent or P = posted) and when it is done processing the message (R = return).  Helps you to see a non-zero LRESULT value returned by WndProc and diagnose re-entrancy problems.

Comment: Thanks very much for the point. However the code which I want to simulate to press `F5` won't work. Did you have any ideas about this issue?